# Adding 7 days to date in xdsoft datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using [XD Soft DateTimePicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) for displaying datepicker.

I have two text-boxes "txtFromDate" and "txtToDate"

---

**What I need?**

When I select a date in "txtFromDate" then the "txtToDate" can only select the next 7 days. ie. max date in "txtToDate" will be +7 days of selected days in "txtFromDate"

---

**What I done so far?**

I have this code

```
jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('#txtFromDate').datetimepicker({
            format: 'd/m/Y',
            onShow: function (ct) {
                this.setOptions({
                    maxDate: jQuery('#txtToDate').val() ? jQuery('#txtToDate').val() : false,
                    formatDate: 'd/m/Y'
                })
            },
            timepicker: false,
        });
        jQuery('#txtToDate').datetimepicker({
            format: 'd/m/Y',
            onShow: function (ct) {
                this.setOptions({
                    minDate: jQuery('#txtFromDate').val() ? jQuery('#txtFromDate').val() : false,
                    maxDate: ???? //Need to set +7days date of txtFromDate here,
                    formatDate: 'd/m/Y'
                })
            },
            timepicker: false,
        });

    });
```

Here I want to add 7 days to the maxDate of txtToDate.

How to add days to the date assigned to maxDate of txtToDate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new method for find out the `future` date.
Please see the code snippet

```
jQuery(function(){
 jQuery('#date_timepicker_start').datetimepicker({
  format:'Y/m/d',
  onShow:function( ct ){
   this.setOptions({
    maxDate:jQuery('#date_timepicker_end').val()?jQuery('#date_timepicker_end').val():false
   })
  },
  timepicker:false
 });
 jQuery('#date_timepicker_end').datetimepicker({
  format:'Y/m/d',
  onShow:function( ct ){
   this.setOptions({
    minDate:jQuery('#date_timepicker_start').val()?jQuery('#date_timepicker_start').val():false,
    maxDate:jQuery('#date_timepicker_start').val()? geFutureDate(jQuery('#date_timepicker_start').val(),7):false, 
   })
  },
  timepicker:false
 });
});


function geFutureDate(date_input, no_of_days){
    var from_date       =new Date(date_input);
     var time_after_7_days   =new Date(from_date).setDate(from_date.getDate()+no_of_days);
    return new Date(time_after_7_days);

}
```